# Psoc 4 ble communicate with windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, ancs, psoc

I want to make an application to get my notifications from an iphone through psoc 4 ble. I'm subscribing to ANCS service, i get the notifications, and after i want that data to send to windows to a java or c# application. What I don't know how to do or if it's possible: how do I make the connection between psoc and windows to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

It calls Serial Communication (UART). You will have two pins Tx and Rx and using them you can easily communicate with windows using terminal applications such as PUTTY

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer have bluetooth on it directly?  If so you can use the microsoft API to call it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916530.aspx

else if your computer does not have bleutooth, you have to use the CySmart dongle and use the C# API cypress provides here:  [CySmart](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/software-and-drivers/cysmart-bluetooth-le-test-and-debug-tool)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)